# Private class in a struct

Tags: class, go, constructor, private

I'm new to Go and couldn’t find a good solution for my problem.
I have 2 types, the first one is private, because I want the programmer to use a constructor. The 2nd type has the first one inside it.

[screenshot of foo bar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRBGi.png)

Sorry, I am not only new on GO, but also on stackoverflow question asking...so that’s why no code, but a screenshot

Comment: Just put them into one package. In Go packages are much wider than in e.g. Java. Take a look at the stdlib how this is done.

Comment: Put your code directly into your question. And don't include screen shots of text. Just copy and paste the text directly.

Comment: Also note: Go doesn't have classes at all, so there's no such thing as a "private class" in Go.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t do that then. Private in go is private to that package, so it’s working as designed. Try working with the tools and see where you end up.

Instead you could:

- Trust the user of your package and leave foo open
- Put both types in the same package
- Have a private field using a public type
- Make the zero value useful so you don’t need a constructor

Lots of options, but also ask yourself do you really need this complex structure of nested structs for the problem at hand?